# Personal Access Token from Azure Key Vault

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-rm

I am using an Azure keyvault to manage some secrets I am using in a deployment pipeline. All of the secrets are working except for a personal access token from Azure DevOps. I am using the personal access token to install an ADO agent on the virtual machines

```
data "azurerm_key_vault" "keyvault" {
  name                = "keyvault"
  resource_group_name = "keyault-RG"
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "pat" {
  name         = "ADOPAT"
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.keyvault.id
}
```

For example, in my virtual machine module I have something like this:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "ado" {
  count                      = length(var.VMs)
  name                       = "${element(var.VMs, count.index)}-TeamServicesAgent"
  virtual_machine_id         = azurerm_virtual_machine.VMs[count.index].id
  publisher                  = "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services"
  type                       = "TeamServicesAgent"
  type_handler_version       = "1.0"
  auto_upgrade_minor_version = true

  settings = <<SETTINGS
 {
  "PATToken": "${data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.pat.value}",
  "VSTSAccountName": "orgname",
  "TeamProject": "${var.ado_project}",
  "DeploymentGroup": "${var.deployment_group}"
 }
SETTINGS


  tags = var.tags
}
```

When I define the PAT as a variable, everything works fine. It's only when I implement the key vault the extension is unable to provision. I don't want to define the PAT as a variable because then I would have the PAT as a plaintext in my code. I don't see many examples online of folks using the ado agent extension, but does anyone have any ideas of what may be causing the issue?

I've tried setting the data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.pat.value to a locals variable but same issue. The issue does not happen when I define the PAT as a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the extension is not getting installed,
Add `depends_on=[ azurerm_virtual_machine.example ]` parameter in azurerm_virtual_machine_extension  block , as it depends on the VM creation.

**Note:**
Make sure the keyvault is given proper permissions in the keyvault block

I tried below code:

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault" "example" {
  name                        = "kasaraexmplkeyvault"
  location                    = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name         = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  enabled_for_disk_encryption = true
  tenant_id                   = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  soft_delete_retention_days  = 7
  purge_protection_enabled    = false
  sku_name = "standard"

  access_policy {
    tenant_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
   object_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id

    
    certificate_permissions = [
      "Create",
      "Delete",
      "DeleteIssuers",
      "Get",
      "GetIssuers",
      "Import",
      "List",
      "ListIssuers",
      "ManageContacts",
      "ManageIssuers",
      "Purge",
      "SetIssuers",
      "Update",
    ]

    key_permissions = [
      "Backup",
      "Create",
      "Decrypt",
      "Delete",
      "Encrypt",
      "Get",
      "Import",
      "List",
      "Purge",
      "Recover",
      "Restore",
      "Sign",
      "UnwrapKey",
      "Update",
      "Verify",
      "WrapKey",
    ]

    secret_permissions = [
      "Backup",
      "Delete",
      "Get",
      "List",
      "Purge",
      "Recover",
      "Restore",
      "Set",
    ]
    storage_permissions = [
      "Get","Set"
    ]
  }

  
}




resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "pat" { 
  name         = "patvalue"
  value        =  "gsdnjgsgjh3.3jgjshgfdj"
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.example.id
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "acctvnkav"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  name                 = "acctsubkav"
 resource_group_name      = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "example" {
  name                = "acctnickav"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "testconfiguration1"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.example.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "examplen" {
  name                     = "kasaraaccsa"
  resource_group_name      = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"

  tags = {
    environment = "staging"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_storage_container" "example" {
  name                  = "vhdskav"
  storage_account_name  = azurerm_storage_account.examplen.name
  container_access_type = "private"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "example" {
  name                  = "acctvmkav"
  resource_group_name      = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.example.id]
  vm_size               = "Standard_F2"

  storage_image_reference {
    publisher = "Canonical"
    offer     = "UbuntuServer"
    sku       = "16.04-LTS"
    version   = "latest"
  }

  storage_os_disk {
    name          = "myosdisk1"
    //vhd_uri       = "${azurerm_storage_account.examplen.primary_blob_endpoint}${azurerm_storage_containern.example.name}/myosdisk1.vhd"
    caching       = "ReadWrite"
    create_option = "FromImage"
  }

  os_profile {
    computer_name  = "hostname"
    admin_username = "testadmin"
    admin_password = "Password1234!"
  }

  os_profile_linux_config {
    disable_password_authentication = false
  }

  tags = {
    environment = "staging"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "example" {
  name                 = "hostname"
  virtual_machine_id   = azurerm_virtual_machine.example.id
  publisher                  = "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services"
  type                       = "TeamServicesAgent"
  type_handler_version       = "1.0"
  auto_upgrade_minor_version = true
  # publisher            = "Microsoft.Azure.Extensions"
  # type                 = "CustomScript"
  # type_handler_version = "2.0"

  settings = <<SETTINGS
 {
  "PATToken": "${azurerm_key_vault_secret.pat.value}",
  "VSTSAccountName": "orgname",
  "TeamProject": "someproject",
  "DeploymentGroup": "somegroup"
 }
SETTINGS

  tags = {
    environment = "Production"
  }

depends_on=[ azurerm_virtual_machine.example ]
}
```

[authenticating_using_the_personal_access_token | terraform registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/microsoft/azuredevops/latest/docs/guides/authenticating_using_the_personal_access_token)

[image]

- PAT may require additional steps to be able to access it from the key vault. [PAT-Azure Devops | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=Windows)
- Try to Create an new Azure AD application in your Azure Active Directory.
- 

Assign the "Key Vault Secrets User" role to that application in the Access policies of your Azure Key Vault.

- Generate a new client secret for the Azure AD application.
- Grant this  application the necessary permissions to read secrets from the Key Vault.

Use the Azure CLI  to set environment variables for the PAT:

```
AZURE_TENANT_ID: "" ,AZURE_CLIENT_ID:"", AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET: "",
KEYVAULT_NAME: "",SECRET_NAME: "".
```

In your Terraform code, use the "azurerm_key_vault_secret" data source to retrieve the PAT from the key vault:

```
    data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "ado_pat" {
      name         = var.secret_name
      key_vault_id = var.key_vault_id
    }

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "ado_agent" {
  name                 = "ado_agent_installation"
  virtual_machine_id   = azurerm_virtual_machine.vm.id
  publisher            = "Microsoft.Compute"
  type                 = "CustomScriptExtension"
  type_handler_version = "1.9"

  settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
        "commandToExecute": "wget https://vs......tar.gz -P /tmp/ && cd /tmp && tar zxvf ........tar.gz && ./config.sh --unattended --url https://dev.azure.com/your-organization --auth pat --token ${data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.ado_pat.value} --pool your-pool --agent your-agent-name .."
    }
SETTINGS
```

}

Extensions:

[image]

Also check [Automate Azure DevOps self-hosted agent installation using Terraform - DEV Community](https://dev.to/officialcookj/automate-azure-devops-self-hosted-agent-installation-using-terraform-27m5)

Comment: Sorry for late follow up, but this worked! I just needed to add the depends_on to my azurerm_virtual_machine_extension block! I never would have tried that...